# Is a posynomial concave under the following conditions?

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity

**Update**

In case anyone is interested, this question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4766980/652310).

---

Consider the following posynomial with respect to the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$:
\begin{align}
f(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k x_1^{a_{1k}} x_2^{a_{2k}} \cdots x_n^{a_{nk}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{a_{ik}}
\end{align}
According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/897393/652310):

> if all of the exponents are nonnegative, and $\sum_i a_{ik}\leq 1$ for each $k=1,2,\dots,K$, then this expression is *concave*.

Translating this statement, if $a_{ik} \geq 0$ for every $i$ and $k$, and if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ik} \leq 1$ for each $k$, then $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is concave with respect to $x_1,\dots,x_n$. I'm trying to formally prove this statement, but I'm not sure how to complete the proof, so I would appreciate any suggestions on this.

We first rewrite $f$ as
\begin{align}
f(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{a_{ik}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \exp\left(\log\left(x_i^{a_{ik}}\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \exp\left(a_{ik}\log\left(x_i\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik}\log\left(x_i\right)\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \exp(\log(c_k)) \cdot \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik}\log\left(x_i\right)\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik}\log\left(x_i\right) + \log(c_k)\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \exp\left[g_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right] \\
\end{align}
where $g_k : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is defined as
$$
g_k(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik}\log\left(x_i\right) + \log(c_k)
$$
To show that $f$ is concave with respect to $x_1,\dots,x_n$, we proceed as follows. Given that $a_{ik} \geq 0$ for every $i$ and $k$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ik} \leq 1$ for each $k$, we want to show that, for each $k = 1,\dots,K$ and for every $t \in [0,1]$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n \in \mathbb R$,
$$
\exp[g_k(tx_1 + (1-t)y_1,\dots,tx_n + (1-t)y_n)] \geq t\exp[g_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)] + (1-t)\exp[g_k(y_1,\dots,y_n)]
$$
We attempt to do this as follows. Because each $\log\left(x_i\right)$ term is concave and monotone increasing in $x_i$, and because $a_{ik} \geq 0$ for each $i$ and $k$, then we can conclude that $g_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a concave and monotone increasing function of $x_1,\dots,x_n$. This means that, for every $t \in [0,1]$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n \in \mathbb R$,
$$
g_k(tx_1 + (1-t)y_1,\dots,tx_n + (1-t)y_n) \geq tg_k(x_1,\dots,x_n) + (1-t)g_k(y_1,\dots,y_n)
$$
Because the $\exp$ function is increasing, then
$$
\exp[g_k(tx_1 + (1-t)y_1,\dots,tx_n + (1-t)y_n)] \geq \exp[tg_k(x_1,\dots,x_n) + (1-t)g_k(y_1,\dots,y_n)]
$$
I'm not sure how to proceed beyond this point. Using the fact that the $\exp$ function is convex does not seem to be helpful here, as this only shows that
$$
\exp[tg_k(x_1,\dots,x_n) + (1-t)g_k(y_1,\dots,y_n)] \leq t\exp[g_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)] + (1-t)\exp[g_k(y_1,\dots,y_n)]
$$
I've not made use of the assumption that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ik} \leq 1$ for each $k$, so I think this should be used somehow.